# What does '< T >' mean in "< T > void someMethod()"?

Tags: java

What does `< T >` mean in `< T > void someMethod()` ? what return type does such function have?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`<T>` is not a return type, `void` is. `<T>` in this case represents a *type variable* which is used in this method only. For example, if I write this:

```
<T> T getFirstValue(List<T> list) {
    return list.get(0);
}
```

this means that if I give the list containing objects of some specific type, it will return an object of this exact type. For example, if I give it a `List<String>`, I know that I'll get back a `String`. The compiler guesses that `T` is actually a `String` so the method will act as

```
String getFirstValue(List<String> list) {
    return list.get(0);
}
```

Comment: One question: can I specify that the implicit parameter is also of type T?

Comment: @user2460978 define "implicit parameter"

Comment: @user2460978 Are you referring to the object the method is called on or something else?

Comment: Exactly, the object the method is called on.

Comment: @user2460978 This type variable is local to this method only, so the object type is something that is external for this method. If you need this type variable to apply to the object, then you have to place it in the class declaration, not in the method.

Answer (score 3):

Here, `T` is the generic argument. See the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html).

The return type is `void`, since the method's signature is `void someMethod()`.

Answer (score 3):

Where T is a normal [generic object representation in java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html).

> The type parameter section, delimited by angle brackets (<>), follows the class name. It specifies the type parameters (also called type variables) T1, T2, ..., and Tn.

[Defining Methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html)

> The return type—the data type of the value returned by the method, or void if the method does not return a value.

Answer (score 3):

In  `< T > void someMethod()` the generic declaration `<T>` doesn't have a function, because T isn't referenced in any other part of the rest of the signature of someMethod. In this case it means nothing and can be removed.

return type is void.